# Maven and dependencies on two different versions of a library

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I am using maven 3.1.1 and I have following problem

I have a **main project** (pom.xml) which will be compiled to WAR file. And it has two modules.

```
<module>module1</module>
<module>module2</module>

...

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
   <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
   <version><1.0/version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
   <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Module 1** has following (please notice version of artifact)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.bar</groupId>
   <artifactId>library</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Module 2** has following (please notice version of artifact)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.bar</groupId>
   <artifactId>library</artifactId>
   <version>2</version>
</dependency>
```

So, as a result my project depends on two versions of the same library.  And the problem is that the library version 2 isn't backward compatible with version 1. So, I can't just include version 2.

I was considering to modify the module 1 to use library version 2, but it make take substantial amount of time. So, I am looking for a way to include both versions of the library.

How can I make sure that:

- Both version of libraries will end up in WAR file? (And I have a feeling that Maven won't put two different versions of the same library under /WEB-INF/lib. So, how to package it, so both versions are end up somehwere inside of war file)
- Module 1 uses the library with version 1
- Module 2 uses the library with version 2

**Update 1 (thoughts on optional and exclusion)**

I read about optional and exclusion of dependencies [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). And I am not sure that it will work.

- Exclusion

Based on the documentation

> Exclusions are set on a specific dependency in your POM, and are targeted at a specific groupId and artifactId. When you build your project, that artifact will not be added to your project's classpath by way of the dependency in which the exclusion was declared.

I believe if I will try to exclude library v2 in my main project, it just won't be included. Main project will build the module2. However, when it will be packaging everything (including a module2) to a WAR file, it will just exclude library V2.

- Optional

Based on the documentation `If a user wants to use functionality related to an optional dependency, they will have to redeclare that optional dependency in their own project.`

So, if I will declare in my module2 dependency on library v2 optional then if I won't redeclare it in the main project, it won't be included to final WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Module should declare a dependency on yourJar2, as normal.

Where you specify that your Project has a dependency on your Module, use the

```
<exclusions>
```

tags to exclude jar version 2 as being 'exported' as a transitive dependency.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>yourGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourJar</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        So your project has a dependency on Jar1
         <dependency>
            <groupId>yourGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourModule</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>yourGroup</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yourJar</artifactId>
                    <version>2</version>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        And now your project has a dependency on yourModule, which will not give you a transitive dependency on yourJar2
```

Comment: Two questions. I am using <module> to include module. Does exclusion work for the module too. Also, where will version 2 of the library copied to? Will it end up inside of module JAR (vs /lib folder of WAR)?

Comment: Within your module's pom, where you declare a dependency on jar2, add <optional>true</optional>. Having a think about the other question!

Comment: I updated a question to include pom.xml pieces to make it a little bit more clear cut case. And I added my thoughts on usage of exclude and optional.